# Button is not working in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

The Button is not working when clicked. It is animating though and I'm not getting any errors. Even if I use 'this.getApplicationContext()', 'view.getContext() or 'data.this.getApplicationContext', it doesn't work. The code in the 'data' class is as under.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.data);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.data_btn_copy_opd_num);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Text Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });`
```

The XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/data"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.stark_student_clinic.data"
    android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:gravity="top|right"
    android:focusable="false">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/data_scrollview">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/data_linearlayout">

            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/data_gridlayout"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="113dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:text="Name : "
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/data_txt_student_name"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:textColorLink="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="78dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:id="@+id/data_imageview_photo"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="71dp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    android:layout_rowSpan="2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="122dp"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:text="OPD Number : "
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/data_txt_student_opd_number"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Material.EditText"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                    android:layout_height="53dp"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:contextClickable="false"
                    android:cursorVisible="false"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:layout_row="1"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="121dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:text="DOB : "
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/data_txt_student_dob"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:layout_row="2"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:enabled="false" />

                <Button
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/data_btn_copy_opd_num"
                    android:layout_column="3"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />

            </GridLayout>

            <TextView
                android:text="Text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="299dp"
                android:id="@+id/data_lbl_falana_dakana" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, the onClick property is not working when it is defined (not done here, in the code posted) and is giving an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method getOPD(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'data_btn_copy_opd_num'

It is implemented in the Class with the following syntax:

```
public void getOPD(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Some Stuff", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using v.getContext() try **getBaseContext()**.That might solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Toast.makeText(activityname.this, "Text Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();**